# Remove the last octet of IP address

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove the last octet of an IP address and I have no idea where to start.

I am currently able to get the host computers IP, but need to alter it.

**Current Code:**

```
Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String
        GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
        Dim strHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

        For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
            If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                GetIPv4Address = ipheal.ToString()
            End If

        Next
        IP = GetIPv4Address
    End Function
```

The above outputs xx.xx.xx.xxx

The goal is to have it output xx.xx.xx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
IP = GetIPv4Address
```

With this:

```
IP = Left(GetIPv4Address, GetIPv4Address.LastIndexOf("."))
```

See more info on [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left(v=vs.110).aspx) and [LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Comment: Getting an 'Expression expected" error after LastIndexOf. Also, do I keep that new line within the function, or put it into the class I want to call it in?---- Edit, just needed to replace ' with " - My fault!